# How to adjust contrast on multiple images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, contrast

I'm using PS6 and I'd like to adjust contrast on multiple opened files.

I've found so far only this [tutorial](http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-play-photoshop-actions-on-multiple-images-with-batch-editing/), however I couldn't find the appropriate option to adjust the contrast. This suggest me that I should create custom action, but I don't think it's the right way of doing it.

So the question is, what's the right way of adjusting contrast on multiple images?

Comment: You can totally do it in photoshop, but lightroom is better for that stuff. Easier and perhaps slightly more flexible too.

Comment: Holding the Option/Alt key down when you select something from `Image > Adjustments >` will load the last used settings. That may help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that tutorial for batch editing and creating an action for contrast is the correct way to add contrast to multiple images.

For that tutorial, you will need to first create the contrast action and then select that action when doing the batch.

[image: pick the right action]

I would make sure the contrast adjustment is on a separate layer and not an image adjustment. This will let you adjust the contrast filter once applied to all images in the batch.

The only downside of this is that every image will use the same contrast adjustment.